How to enter PIN to unlock SIM via command line / powershell / tool in Windows 10
I am searching for a way to unlock a SIM card using it's PIN in a mobile broadband adapter via the command line (in a batch script).
All I have found so far were any AT commands which I cannot send to this specific adapter (Intel 7360 LTE-A). It has two serial interfaces but both of them are locked and can never be opened.
Is tried a software for handling SIM cards from https://awx.black-it.eu/en/software/mobile%20broadband%20sms%20toolkit/index.htm which WAS ABLE to unlock the SIM card. So there must be a way to do this without using the Windows interface.
I know I could remove the PIN via the Windows interface, but I do not want to do that. The laptop is encrypted, meaning even if it got stolen, no one could get to the "hardcoded" PIN. But if I remove it from the SIM card, the card would be easily usable.
Does anyone know, how to send AT commands to the adapter itself, or know a utility/tool or commandline or powershell way to do automatically unlock the SIM card at boot?

Something like can do the work:
First open Device manager to get the COM port of you SIM. Can be something like: COM21
Then set the connection parameters: mode COM21 BAUD=115200 Try with other values, 9600 is also good candidate. Your software may tell you what is the speed of connection.
and next send unlock command set /p x="AT+CPIN=1234"  >\\.\COM21 where 1234 is your pin. The answer should be OK if SIM card is unlocked.

As stated in my original question, there are no COM ports, that can be opened attached to the card. There are two ports visible, but they both can never be opend and Windows always shows an error when trying.

@Angel-Oh-No, in this article I see it appear as COM port. Or it is something different? https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000181828/dell-wireless-5820-intel-7360-firmware-flash-failures-during-imaging

There are two COM ports in device manager, yes. But THEY CANNOT BE OPENED!!!!

@Angel-Oh-No, how you try to open them? Did you try with putty to make connection?

I tried putty, I tried "echo ATCOMMAND > COMx" and they are always "unavailable". Please believe me I know how to access serial ports. These two, which are attached to the modem cannot be opened. Is there ANY utility out there, which can be given the SIM Pin as a command line argument to unlock the SIM card? It technically works with 3rd party software, as confirmed in my first post. There must be an API for this.

@Angel-Oh-No, in such case I have no idea. Sometime there is custom hardware which xan be accessed only via API and/or specialized software :(

Exactly! This adapter CAN be obviously accessed by third party software as the "Mobile Broadband SMS Toolkit" linked above can unlock it. But I want to automate the process and this specfic tool cannot do that... very frustrating.
